# Benchmark profiling

Tags: cuda, profiling

Let's say that I have an application benchmark to execute from the linux terminal. I wish to wrap a profiler around it so that I can gather information for the exeuction of the benchmark such as CPU utilization etc. I have written the profiler in C. How do I wrap this profiler around the benchmark so that I do not have to invoke these two separately.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably many possible solutions.

Assuming my own custom "profiler" application is called `profiler`, I could create a bash shell script named `profile` like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
./profiler &
./$1
```

I could then invoke it with:

```
./profile myapp
```

Assuming `myapp` is the name of the app that I want to run concurrently with the "profiler".

Comment: Can something be done during the compilation of the benchmark itself so that when benchmark is invoked, the profiler automatically performs the operation on the benchmark?

Comment: There are commands like [system](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system) which allow you to execute arbitrary system-level commands (so you could, for example, launch your profiler to run in the background, and the systme command will then return control to your benchmark application).  Most of this line of questioning seems to be not relevant to CUDA.  You might get better responses if you tag your question differently.